# How can I get the updates in view model when data changes in a grid bound to an Observable Collection<T> in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a few combo boxes and columns bound to a grid, when the user 
    changes the selection in the combo box or edits a field. I would like 
     to capture the changes in my view model. The grid is bound to an 
     ObservableCollection

T has INotifyPropertyChanged, and currently I am capturing the changes 
     in the class T

```
<c1:C1FlexGrid 
    Name="grdInteractions" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Interactions, Mode=TwoWay}"
    >
    <c1:C1FlexGrid.Columns>
        <c1:Column 
            Width="80" 
            Header="Code"  
            ColumnName="InteractionCode" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            IsReadOnly="true"
            Binding="{Binding Parent}" 
            />
        <c1:Column 
            Width="65" Header="Strategy"
            >
            <c1:Column.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox 
                        Name="cbStrategy" 
                        DisplayMemberPath="StrategyDesc" 
                        SelectedValuePath="StrategyCode" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Strategies}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding StrategyItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        />
                </DataTemplate>
            </c1:Column.CellTemplate>
        </c1:Column>
    </c1:C1FlexGrid.Columns>
</c1:C1FlexGrid>
```

C#

```
public class Interaction : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string InteractionCode { get; set; }
    public List<Strategy> Strategies
    {
        get
        {
            return _strategies;
        }
        set
        {
            _strategies = value;
        }
    }
    public Strategy StrategyItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _strategyItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _strategyItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StrategyItem");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks fine, does it not work? Do you get an exception? what is the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show us the OnPropertyChanged method? Also, in your binding statements try to use 'UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged' to ensure binding update from UI to Code behind like so : SelectedItem="{Binding StrategyItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"

Comment: When I change the selected item it fires the StrategyItem in the class Interaction, and nothing occurs in the viewmodel.

Comment: I did try using the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Comment: public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;protected void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }

Comment: What you are trying to achieve , which is not working.

Comment: The  view model is not getting any updates when the bound T value in  the datagrid changes. For example if I select another value from the combo box dropdown. The CollectionChanged does nor fire. I subscribed to the CollectionChanged event.                                       
      void Interactions_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Collection Changed - do something
        }

Comment: The CollectionChanged event shouldn't fire if you only change your selection. I think you probably want to be using the SelectionChanged event. Also try binding to SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem